# How to use an optional parameter in django URL

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want solution for how Django URL work without any optional parameter or with optional parameter.

Here is the URL structure that I want:

```
path('<slug:category_slug>-comparison/<slug:brand_slug1>-vs-<slug:brand_slug2>-vs-<slug:brand_slug3>/',views.compare_brand)
```

Now I want something like 1st two slugs for comparison is compulsory so, as per the above URL

```
path('<slug:category_slug>-comparison/<slug:brand_slug1>-vs-<slug:brand_slug2>',views.compare_brand)
```

This is working fine because this are compulsory url parameter but I want to pass optional url from 2nd 'vs' to brand_slug3.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like this in django urls.py. But you can pass a URL Query string to the view. For example, if you hit this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/Category1-comparison/Brand1-vs-Brand2/?vs=Brand3
```

Then you can catch the `Brand3` value from `request.GET`. Like this:

```
def compare_brand(request, category_slug, brand_slug1, brand_slug2):
     brand_slug3 = request.GET.get('vs')
```

#### A better solution:

Maybe a better approach is to use URL query string all together. Because, in that way the url will be much cleaner. For example:

```
# url

path('/comparison/<slug:category_slug>/', compare_brand)

# view
def compare_brand(request, category_slug):
    brands = request.GET.getlist('brands')
    if len(brands) < 2:
        raise Exception('Need 2 brands atleast')

# browser url
http://localhost:8000/comparison/Cat1/?brands=Brand1,Brand2
```

## From comments

You can create another url pointing to the same view

```
# url
path('<slug:category_slug>-comparison/<slug:brand_slug1>-vs-<slug:brand_slug2>-vs-<slug:brand_slug3>/',views.compare_brand),
path('<slug:category_slug>-comparison/<slug:brand_slug1>-vs-<slug:brand_slug2>/',views.compare_brand)

# view

def compare_brand(request, category_slug, brand_slug1, brand_slug2, brand_slug3=None):
    if brand_slug3:
       # do something
```

Comment: No @ruddra actually I don't want like this its break SEO structure.

Comment: what if I make another URL path for 3 brand_slug?

Comment: @Sahilshaikh yep you can. Please see the #From comments section of the answer

Comment: can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375404/how-to-limit-prefetch-record-in-django